# Native-base icon appear is not display at the left side

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am using native-base library. I have a icon menu which when click open the left panel. I have icon inside header and left. But I am not sure why this icon is appear at somewhere middle as shown in figure below. It should appear at left side.

[image]

This is the code I am trying. Can anybody tell why this error appear.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { Header, Left, Right, Icon } from 'native-base';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Header>
                    <Left>
                        <Icon name="menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} />
                    </Left>
                </Header>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Left` or `Body` or `Right` with any NativeBase component, you must include these 3, to align the components

So in your case,

```
<Header>
  <Left><Icon /></Left>
  <Body />
  <Right />
</Header>
```